# Quickest way to execute stored procedure in c# requiring least amount of code

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, data-access-layer

I'm going to grab the results in a collection of entity. I don't just need the IDataReader object. So above should be answered considering that I've large no of parameters and many columns of data is getting returned by the SP.

Please provide reasons.

A few might be

1. Drag and drop on to a DBML designer and then calling it by linq to sql. That's very good. But that also generates lot of code for the DBML. Simpler is better.
2. Getting IDataReader by doing `ExecuteReader` and then passing IDataReader to factory to create it's object. Good and simple. But requires lot of coding. Below is required for each column returned.

> ```
> int nameIndex = dataReader.GetOrdinal("Name");
> if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(nameIndex)){
>    myObject.Name = dataReader.GetString(nameIndex);
> }
> ```

Are there any other simpler option for this?

**UPDATE** 
@Heinzi's answer simplifies the process of handling the results. Is there any better way to handle large number of parameters also?

Comment: What does it matter what code your L2S model generates? It's not like you have to manually write and maintain that file since it's generated for you...

Comment: Agreed. It's very good. I just want to know if there are any other better options available which others are using.

Comment: Okie dokie, I just read it as "it generates a lot of code therefore it's bad". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to DataReaders, you can save some code by writing an extension method on IDataReader, i.e., something like this (untested):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataReader reader, string field, T defaultValue)
{
    int index = reader.GetOrdinal(field);
    if (reader.IsDBNull(index)) {
        return defaultValue;
    } else {
        return (T)(reader[name]);
    }
}
```

This would reduce your factory code to

```
myObject.Name = dataReader.GetValue<string>("name", Nothing)
```

Of course, countless variants of this extension method are possible (with or without defaultValue, target field passed as a ref parameter to get exactly the same behavior as your code, etc.).

---

Otherwise, you could use DataSets instead of DataReaders, where an extension method like this already exists. You create your DataSet like this (instead of executing `myCommand.ExecuteReader`):

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
adapter.Fill(dataSet);
var table = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Then you can access your data using [DataRowExtensions.Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
myObject.Name = table.Field<string>("name");
myObject.Age = table.Field<int?>("age") ?? 30;   // default value if DBNull
```

Comment: +1. Extension method is simply fantastic! Datasets are slow. So wouldn't like to used them. Although thanks for letting us know the usefulness of `Field` extension method.

Comment: ! In the same way, do you know any better way to handle large number of parameters?

Comment: @Ismail: [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) is already quite efficient, since it requires only one line per parameter.